# xmpp client using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp, google-talk

I want to create an XMPP client using google app engine, ie the objective is that any user should be able to use my site as a portal to chat on Gtalk (via XMPP).

I tried using the XMPP library of GAE, but couldn't find a way to send/receive messages using the user's ID instead of the App's Jabber ID. All the documentations are about how to create a gtalk bot (whereas I want to create a site that could be used as a portal to chat).

I was able to create an offline app using python-xmpp which could be used as a portal to chat, but i don't know how to get that onto the GAE server (and if it's possible).

Also, is there any alternative to XMPP to create a gtalk portal using GAE?

Any Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible - applications on AppEngine can not impersonate other users over XMPP.

Docs clearly state [which XMPP addresses can be used](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/#Python_XMPP_addresses).